# Does changing the height where an object is placed contradict the Law of Conservation of Energy?

Tags: energy-conservation

I read this question in the textbook, "Concepts of Physics, Vol. 1":

"When you lift a box from the floor and put it on an almirah the potential energy of the box increases, but there is no change in its kinetic energy. Is it a violation of conservation of energy?"

The answer ofcourse would be no but how I am not sure?

I first thought that it would have taken energy from something else thus keeping the total energy constant but then realised that this argument was rubbish as I could not think of anything that lost energy.

The potential energy here is given by
$$U = -mgh$$
h increases and U must be constant so g must decrease and it does decrease. But the decrease is minuscule and I have a feeling that even this line of reasoning is wrong.

So how to resolve this seeming paradox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When **you** lift a box from the floor and put it on an almirah the potential energy of the box increases, but there is no change in its kinetic energy. Is it a violation of conservation of energy?

> I could not think of anything that lost energy

You lost energy.

Comment: So the earlier reasoning was not rubbish indeed.

Comment: @Laplace'sDemon yes. The reasoning is not rubbish